# PreviewKeyDown of ComboboxItem

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a UserControl that add Combobox in it. I use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF).

I want to checked the check box when press space key.

I add a `EventSetter` on Combobox resource .

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
       <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="OnPreviewKeyDown" />
    </Style> 
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

but don't raise it.

How do raise keydown on ComboboxItem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Snoop (link to snoop: [here](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)) or XAML Spy (link to XAML Spy: [here](http://xamlspy.com/download)) to understand where the event is handled. And try to hook it (here is the link: [WPF - catch events even if they are already handled](http://blog.lexique-du-net.com/index.php?post/2010/02/18/WPF-catch-events-even-if-already-handled)) by a behavior or using an attached property (or in code behind).

Regards.